# Synonym paging → virtual-memory?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

We have [pager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pager) and [paging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paging). [paging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paging) is going to get used for virtual memory whether we want it or not, so I suggest making [paging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paging) a synonym of [virtual-memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-memory) (and leave [pager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pager) for `less` and friends). I figure seeing [paging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paging) redirect to [virtual-memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtual-memory) should be enough of a hint to try another tag when you're after a pager.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mattdm suggested the synonym already, so I approved it and merged